# why I can't use qt to program in linux normally

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am new to QT,so I want to write a "Hello World" to learn QT first.

1.First,I install the QT5 on my computer.(Archlinux).

```
sudo pacman -S qt5-base qt5
```

Then,I install qt-creator.

```
sudo pacman -S qtcreator
```

And,I use QT creator to create a new project(I select `Qt widgets Application`).

the IDE generate some code automatically.I don't add any code to the source file.

`.pro:`

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-05-21T14:48:56
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact 
warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated 
APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain 
version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all 
the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I think it should generate a blank window when I build and run.

However,When I try to build and run.There are so many issues.

The Picture

[image]

I don't know why this happen.

Then I try to use the official examples.I follow the official tutorial [Building and Running an Example](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-example-application.html).Howerver,same issues occurs  when I try to build and run.

2.Wyzard say that I should use `std=c++11` to compile the program.

So,I create a `main.cpp` file.

`main.cpp:`

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QPushButton>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
    hello.resize(100, 30);

    hello.show();
    return app.exec();
 }
```

Then,I use qmake to generate a makefile.

```
$qmake -project

$qmake
```

And,I add `-std=c++11` to the compile flags.

`make`

`output:`

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -std=c++11 -I. -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/ -o hello.o hello.cpp

In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qglobal.h:1129,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from hello.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:222:18: error: ‘atomic’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     typedef std::atomic<X> Type;
                  ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:225:23: error: ‘atomic’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     T load(const std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:225:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T load(const std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                             ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:231:32: error: ‘atomic’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     T load(const volatile std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:231:38: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T load(const volatile std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                      ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:231:7: error: ‘template<class X> template<class T> static T QAtomicOps<X>::load(int)’ cannot be overloaded
     T load(const volatile std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
       ^~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:225:7: error: with ‘template<class X> template<class T> static T QAtomicOps<X>::load(int)’
     T load(const std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
       ^~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:237:30: error: ‘atomic’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     T loadAcquire(const std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:237:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T loadAcquire(const std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                    ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:243:39: error: ‘atomic’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     T loadAcquire(const volatile std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:243:45: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T loadAcquire(const volatile std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                             ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:243:7: error: ‘template<class X> template<class T> static T QAtomicOps<X>::loadAcquire(int)’ cannot be overloaded
     T loadAcquire(const volatile std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:237:7: error: with ‘template<class X> template<class T> static T QAtomicOps<X>::loadAcquire(int)’
     T loadAcquire(const std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:249:21: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     void store(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:249:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void store(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                           ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:255:28: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     void storeRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                            ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:255:34: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void storeRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                  ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:263:33: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static inline bool ref(std::atomic<T> &_q_value)
                                 ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:263:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static inline bool ref(std::atomic<T> &_q_value)
                                       ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:269:35: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static inline bool deref(std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:269:41: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static inline bool deref(std::atomic<T> &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                         ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:279:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static bool testAndSetRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:279:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static bool testAndSetRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qglobal.h:1129,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from hello.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:288:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static bool testAndSetAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:288:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static bool testAndSetAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:297:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static bool testAndSetRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:297:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static bool testAndSetRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:306:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static bool testAndSetOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:306:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static bool testAndSetOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T expectedValue, T newValue, T *currentValue = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:318:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static T fetchAndStoreRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:318:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static T fetchAndStoreRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:324:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static T fetchAndStoreAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:324:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static T fetchAndStoreAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:330:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static T fetchAndStoreRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:330:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static T fetchAndStoreRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:336:40: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     static T fetchAndStoreOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:336:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static T fetchAndStoreOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                              ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:345:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAddRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:345:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAddRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:351:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAddAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:351:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAddAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:357:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAddRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:357:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAddRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:363:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAddOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:363:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAddOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:369:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndSubRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:369:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndSubRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:375:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndSubAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:375:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndSubAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:381:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndSubRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:381:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndSubRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:387:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndSubOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:387:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndSubOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:393:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAndRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:393:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAndRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:399:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAndAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:399:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAndAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:405:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAndRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:405:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAndRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:411:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndAndOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:411:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndAndOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:417:30: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndOrRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:417:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndOrRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                    ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:423:30: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndOrAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:423:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndOrAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                    ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:429:30: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndOrRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:429:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndOrRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                    ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:435:30: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndOrOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:435:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndOrOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                    ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:441:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndXorRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:441:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndXorRelaxed(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:447:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndXorAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:447:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndXorAcquire(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:453:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndXorRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:453:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndXorRelease(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:459:31: error: ‘std::atomic’ has not been declared
     T fetchAndXorOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:459:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     T fetchAndXorOrdered(std::atomic<T> &_q_value, typename QAtomicAdditiveType<T>::AdditiveT valueToAdd) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qglobal.h:1129,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from hello.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static T QAtomicOps<X>::load(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:227:16: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
                ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:227:30: error: ‘memory_order_relaxed’ is not a member of ‘std’
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
                              ^~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static T QAtomicOps<X>::load(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:233:16: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
                ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:233:30: error: ‘memory_order_relaxed’ is not a member of ‘std’
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
                              ^~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static T QAtomicOps<X>::loadAcquire(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:239:16: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
                ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:239:30: error: ‘memory_order_acquire’ is not a member of ‘std’
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
                              ^~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static T QAtomicOps<X>::loadAcquire(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:245:16: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
                ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:245:30: error: ‘memory_order_acquire’ is not a member of ‘std’
         return _q_value.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
                              ^~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static void QAtomicOps<X>::store(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:251:9: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         _q_value.store(newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed);
         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:251:24: error: ‘newValue’ was not declared in this scope
         _q_value.store(newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:251:34: error: ‘memory_order_relaxed’ is not a member of ‘std’
         _q_value.store(newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                                  ^~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static void QAtomicOps<X>::storeRelease(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:257:9: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         _q_value.store(newValue, std::memory_order_release);
         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:257:24: error: ‘newValue’ was not declared in this scope
         _q_value.store(newValue, std::memory_order_release);
                        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:257:34: error: ‘memory_order_release’ is not a member of ‘std’
         _q_value.store(newValue, std::memory_order_release);
                                  ^~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static bool QAtomicOps<X>::ref(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:265:18: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         return ++_q_value != 0;
                  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static bool QAtomicOps<X>::deref(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:271:18: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         return --_q_value != 0;
                  ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qglobal.h:1129,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from hello.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h: In static member function ‘static bool QAtomicOps<X>::testAndSetRelaxed(int)’:
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:281:20: error: ‘_q_value’ was not declared in this scope
         bool tmp = _q_value.compare_exchange_strong(expectedValue, newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                    ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:281:53: error: ‘expectedValue’ was not declared in this scope
         bool tmp = _q_value.compare_exchange_strong(expectedValue, newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h:281:68: error: ‘newValue’ was not declared in this scope
         bool tmp = _q_value.compare_exchange_strong(expectedValue, newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~

.......
```

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: Please don't insert links to pictures, but the code and relevant error codes in the question.

Comment: Please share `.pro` file

Comment: I am working on Arch Linux and I have not had any problems, you could show your code and your .pro file.

Comment: execute: `sudo pacman -S qt5-tools`

Comment: Hmm, `std::atomic` should definitely exist when using `-std=c++11`.  And you would've gotten an error from an `#include <atomic>` line in that header if it wasn't available.

Comment: I am sorry,I don't understand.what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know, and I'm unable to reproduce the problem.  I installed Arch (in a VM) from the 2017.05.01 CD, then installed QT Creator and created a project as you described, and it built without errors.  I didn't even need `-std=c++11`.  It's possible that your `<atomic>` header is corrupted; try reinstalling the `gcc` package.

Comment: Today,When I open the qt-createor  again,everything is ok.I am confused... Thank you for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot shows that the errors are in a file called `qatomic_cxx11.h`, and they relate to features that were added to the language in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11).  It's likely that your compiler is treating the code as C++98, where things like `std::atomic` don't exist.

You probably need to add `-std=c++11` as a compile option, to tell it to compile as C++11.  (Or, if your compiler supports it, use `std=c++14` to compile as [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14).)

Comment: Since this is a Qt question, the proper answer would be to add `CONFIG += c++11` or `CONFIG += c++14` to the `.pro` file, delete the build folder, and build the project again.

Comment: Today,When I open the qt-createor  again,everything is ok.I am confused... Thank you for everyone.